# Installing nodejs via nvm fails

Tags: node.js, nvm

I spend a lot of time and tons pages...

I have a an strange issue while installing nodejs on ubuntu 14.04 server (via nvm).  When i run "nvm install 0.12.7" nvm gives me an answer:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nodejs.org
grep: /root/.nvm/bin/node-v0.12.7-linux-x86/node-v0.12.7-linux-x86.tar.gz: No such file or folder
Binary download failed, trying source.
nvm: install v0.12.7 failed!
```

If i type "nvm install 0.12.7" one more time, i got answer message:

```
Version '0.12.7' - not found - try 'nvm ls-remote' to browser available versions
```

I was try to install all available versions, also with -s postfix, but has a same error. I was try to install nodejs with sudo & from root. Same error. I was try uninstall and reinstall nvm with sudo and from root. Same error.

If i re-login and type nvm instal..... - I'll get a first fail, then second and so on.

I can install nodejs using apt-get, but i need to use nvm, it must be able to test project on many nodejs versus installed. Hope for help!

Comment: Try `nvm install 0.12`? And are you by chance using a proxy server on that computer?

Comment: @remus your suggestion gives same error message (# 1). And there is no proxy, no firewalls, etc...

Comment: Can you get to nodejs.org in your browser? Can you use curl natively?

Comment: @remus yes, i have connection to nodejs.org & i can use curl. The issue about nvm but not in my connection. I use 32bit Ubuntu 14.04.2 server. And just now i get anower pc with 64bit Ubuntu 14.04.2 desktop version. I have just install nodejs v0.12.7 via nvm with no problem on the same internet connection. Seems to be a bug in Ubuntu 32b server with no some kind of resolution...

Comment: What shell are you running it in?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue on ubuntu 14.04. Simply append v in front of version. That is the command will be `nvm install v0.12.7`.
And it worked like charm for me!

Answer (score 1):

Instructions to Install Nodejs latest Version for Ubuntu via NVM:

P.s - In order to Unistall NVM:

rm -rf $NVM_DIR ~/.npm ~/.bower

Start With This:

1. curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash

Exit the Terminal and Start Again

2. nvm install 14.4.0 (or your preferable version)

3....
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt-get update

4...
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -

5...
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

6..
sudo apt install build-essential

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding the `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh (or bash ~/.nvm/nvm.sh)` causes it to complain: N/A: version "N/A" is not yet installed. Even nvm list causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

With me, it worked when I added versions directories manually

```
mkdir ~/.nvm/versions
```

Answer (score 0):

On that link https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2771 was exactly what happened to me. I just uninstalled the curl snap package and installed it again using apt and finally removed nvm and reinstalled it again, all following the instructions on their github repo https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#uninstalling--removal